# Dual boot with encrypted Windows partition

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows

I tried to make the Windows option on GRUB boot menu the default by following the instructions I found on the internet. The instructions were good, graceful but since I encrypted the Windows partition after I installed Ubuntu, the graceful approach didn't work for me when I did `update-grub`. The option simply disappeared because decryption does not work under Ubuntu.

I found on the Internet some codes for `grub.conf` to restore Windows startup. It was successful but there is an error message after I select the Windows option.

I wonder whether `update-grub` *automatically backs up a copy* of `grub.conf` or any other config files it changes? If so, I can probably retrieve that config and get rid of the error message.

I didn't mean to encrypt, it's a company PC and encryption of Windows partition is mandatory. I do not want to decrypt the Windows partition, fix GRUB and encrypt again - it simply takes too much time.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Windows Bootloader on another partition then chainload from GRUB then from there boot into Windows.